# Laravel 4 display list of data into form selection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade, formbuilder

How do I display a list of books in laravel form builder selection?

BookController.php

```
$book_names = Book::all();

return View::make('books')->with('book_names', $book_names);
```

At the moment I only know how do manually input data:

```
{{ Form::select('book_name', array(
  'book1' => 'book1', 
  'book2' => 'book2', 
  'book3' => 'book3') 
}}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
{{ Form::select('book_name', array(
  @foreach($book_names as $book_name)
    $book_name->name => $book_name->name, 
  @endforeach 
}}
```

But obviously It won't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meet the `lists()` method. It allows you to create an array from one or two (key and value) properties of a collection:

```
$book_names = Book::lists('name');

return View::make('books')->with('book_names', $book_names);
```

And then simply pass that array:

```
{{ Form::select('book_name', $book_names) }}
```

Comment: can we display lists as array key and value? for example $user=Auth::user()->roles->lists('name'). Can we do like this echo $user[0], $user[1]. Obviously it won't work.

Comment: @MaXi32 In Laravel 5.1 you need to add a `all()` at the end to get the actual array: `$user=Auth::user()->roles->lists('name')->all()`